# Can generics and (super?) type tokens help to build a type-safe news aggregator?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have this basic `News` interface

```
interface News {
    String getHeader();
    String getText();
}
```

and concrete classes like `SportsNews` and `FinancialNews` to provide specific methods like `getStockPrice()`, `getSport()` and so on. News are intended to be dispatched to a

```
interface Subscriber<N extends News> {
    void onNews(N news);
}
```

The problem is how to register and maintain subscriptions. The first approach I tried was using a central `Aggregator`, keeping a map between `Class<T>` objects and `Set<Subscriber<T>>`, but soon this approach revealed unviable. Here is the desired API

```
public class Aggregator {

    public <N extends News> void subscribe(Subscriber<N> subscriber) {
        // TODO somehow (super type token) extract N and 
        // add the item to the set retrieved by getSubscribersFor()
    }

    public <N extends News> void dispatch(N news) {
        for (Subscriber<N> subscriber: getSubscribersFor(news.getClass())) {
            subscriber.onNews(news);
        }
    }

    private <N extends News> Set<Subscriber<N>> getSubscribersFor(Class<N> k) {
        // TODO retrieve the Set for the specified key from the Map
    }
}
```

Is there any alternative to be type safe? Can Java solve this problem at all? I put [this little demo online](http://pastebin.com/LVbcw0Nv) to help you better understand what the problem really is.

**UPDATE**

An alternative would be to make `Aggregator` itself parameterized with the actual news type. This would be ok, except that it's a chicken and egg problem: now one needs to find a way to retrieve the aggregator. In Java there's no way to express the following

```
interface News {
    static Aggregator<CurrentClass> getAggregator();
}
```

- `static` method can't be `abstract`
- there's no way to reference the *current type* in a type argument

Comment: Nothing is wrong. The `Aggregator` doesn't compile because `getSubscribersFor()` doesn't return anything and it should, but that's the point of the question...

Comment: I get error in `dispatch`: incompatible types/found:  Subscriber<capture#847 of ? extends News>/required: Subscriber<N>

Comment: @MiserableVariable `Aggregator` doesn't compile. I put the signatures to describe the desired API, but definitely I asked this question because I can't compile it... Either one method works, or the other, that's the problem

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. I thought you said `Aggregator` does not compile because `getSubscribersFor`. That is not the only reason it does not compile, another (more important) error is that `getSubscribersFor(news.getClass()` does not return a `Set<Subscriber<N>>`, because `news` can be any other subtype of `N`

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code a number of times, depending on my current attempt. Forget *why* it doesn't compile, and just make it run :) Keep the API (`subscribe` and `dispatch`), all the rest can be freely changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I would do. If you can use Guava (a Google library written and used by Google), I recommend scrolling down and looking at the other solution first.

### Vanilla Java

First, start by adding a method to get the class from your subscribers:

```
public interface Subscriber<N extends News> {
    void onNews(N news);
    Class<N> getSupportedNewsType();
}
```

Then when implementing:

```
public class MySubscriber implements Subscriber<MyNews> {

    // ...

    public Class<MyNews> getSupportedNewsType() {
        return MyNews.class;
    }
}
```

In your aggregator, include a map where the keys and values aren't typed:

```
private Map<Class<?>, Set<Subscriber<?>> subscribersByClass = ... ;
```

Also note that Guava has a multimap implementation that will do this key to multiple values stuff for you. Just Google "Guava Multimap" and you'll find it.

To register a subscriber:

```
public <N extends News> void register(Subscriber<N> subscriber) {
    // The method used here creates a new set and puts it if one doesn't already exist
    Set<Subscriber<?>> subscribers = getSubscriberSet(subscriber.getSupportedNewsType());
    subscribers.add(subscriber);
}
```

And to dispatch:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked");
public <N extends News> void dispatch(N news) {
    Set<Subscriber<?>> subs = subscribersByClass.get(news.getClass());
    if (subs == null)
        return;

    for (Subscriber<?> sub : subs) {
        ((Subscriber<N>) sub).onNews(news);
    }
}
```

Notice the cast here. This will be safe because of the nature of the generics between the `register` method and the `Subscriber` interface, provided no one does something ridiculously wrong, like raw-typing such as `implements Subscriber` (no generic argument). The `SuppressWarnings` annotation suppresses warnings about this cast from the compiler.

And your private method to retrieve subscribers:

```
private Set<Subscriber<?>> getSubscriberSet(Class<?> clazz) {
    Set<Subscriber<?>> subs = subscribersByClass.get(news.getClass());
    if (subs == null) {
        subs = new HashSet<Subscriber<?>>();
        subscribersByClass.put(subs);
    }
    return subs;
}
```

Your `private` methods and fields do not need to be type safe. It won't cause any problems anyway since Java's generics are implemented via erasure, so all of the sets here will be just a set of objects anyway. Trying to make them type safe will only lead to nasty, unnecessary casts that have no bearing on its correctness.

What *does* matter is that your `public` methods are type safe. The way the generics are declared in `Subscriber` and the public methods on `Aggregator`, the only way to break it is via raw types, like I stated above. In short, every `Subscriber` passed to register is *guaranteed* to accept the types that you're registering it for as long as there's no unsafe casts or raw typing.

---

### Using Guava

Alternatively, you can take a look at Guava's `EventBus`. This would be easier, IMO, for what you're trying to do.

Guava's `EventBus` class uses annotation-driven event dispatching instead of interface-driven. It's really simple. You won't have a `Subscriber` interface anymore. Instead, your implementation will look like this:

```
public class MySubscriber {
    // ...

    @Subscribe
    public void anyMethodNameYouWant(MyNews news) {
        // Handle news
    }
}
```

The `@Subscribe` annotation signals to Guava's `EventBus` that it should remember that method later for dispatching. Then to register it and dispatch events, use an `EventBus` isntance:

```
public class Aggregator {
    private EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();

    public void register(Object obj) {
        eventBus.register(obj);
    }

    public void dispatch(News news) {
        eventBus.dispatch(news);
    }
}
```

This will automatically find the methods that accept the `news` object and do the dispatching for you. You can even subscribe more than once in the same class:

```
public class MySubscriber {
    // ...

    @Subscribe
    public void anyMethodNameYouWant(MyNews news) {
        // Handle news
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void anEntirelyDifferentMethod(MyNews news) {
        // Handle news
    }
}
```

Or for multiple types within the same subscriber:

```
public class MySubscriber {
    // ...

    @Subscribe
    public void handleNews(MyNews news) {
        // Handle news
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void handleNews(YourNews news) {
        // Handle news
    }
}
```

Lastly, `EventBus` respects hierarchical structures, so if you have a class that extends `MyNews`, such as `MyExtendedNews`, then dispatching `MyExtendedNews` events will also be passed to those that care about `MyNews` events. Same goes for interfaces. In this way, you can even create a global subscriber:

```
public class GlobalSubscriber {
    // ...

    @Subscribe
    public void handleAllTheThings(News news) {
        // Handle news
    }
}
```

Comment: It's for an Android project, and Guava would make the package too big. Anyway, +1. Just a couple of points: 1. `getSupportedNewsType()` isn't needed, since the aggregator can easily extract the type parameter itself programmatically, so one doesn't need to override that in each subscriber 2. Since I can't use a `Multimap`, I need to find a way to get the appropriate `Set<Subscriber<N>>` from my `Map`. That's what my private method `getSubscribersFor(Class)` was for

Comment: To put it plainly, on runtime, Java doesn't care about what type is on the subscriber. What you want is compile-time verification. (You won't get runtime verification because of erasure). It doesn't matter what your `getSubscribersFor` method returns because ultimately, it's just going to be a set of objects that all have an `onNews` method that accepts objects. As long as your public method signatures are type-safe, the underlying method of storing them doesn't matter. I'll update my answer to reflect this a little better.

Comment: I think you got the point. The whole thing of using generics instead of raw types everywhere is to guarantee that if there's something wrong, it fails as soon as possible (ie at compile time). In this case, it seems I can only use generics to make the `Subscriber` API look nicer, because everywhere else I used unchecked casts (potentially unsafe)

Comment: I accepted your answer, but I think you should clean it up and organize all of your code into a single compilable and executable unit ;) Currently, there are some typos and the work can't overall be used by others for future reference. Again, I suggest to drop the `getSupportedNewsTypes()` since it can be achieved via reflection (and there are some annoyances with `getSubscribersFor(Class)` and subclasses, but this is another point)

Comment: @Brian interesting. how well does Guava handle generics? for example, `class Parent<T>{ @Subscribe void foo(T){...} }    class Child extends Parent<Number>{}`. now register a `new Child()`, then dispatch an `Integer`, what happens?

Comment: @irreputable `EventBus` uses the types available at runtime, not compile-time, so `void foo(T)` would be `void foo(Object)` on runtime. This means that `EventBus` wouldn't handle it as `Number`, but as `Object`.

Comment: Seems like a lot of things in Java go "First, start by adding a method to get the class from ____" :)

Answer (score 1):

You *will* need to send the `class` parameter to `dispatch`. The following compiles for me, not sure if that meets your needs:

```
import java.util.Set;

interface News {
    String getHeader();
    String getText();
}

interface SportsNews extends News {}

interface Subscriber<N extends News> {
    void onNews(N news);
}


class Aggregator {

    public <N extends News> void subscribe(Subscriber<N> subscriber, Class<N> clazz) {
        // TODO somehow (super type token) extract N and 
        // add the item to the set retrieved by getSubscribersFor()
    }

    public <N extends News> void dispatch(N item, Class<N> k) {
        Set<Subscriber<N>> l = getSubscribersFor(k);
        for (Subscriber<N> s : l) {
            s.onNews(item);
        }
    }

    private <N extends News> Set<Subscriber<N>> getSubscribersFor(Class<N> k) {
        return null;
        // TODO retrieve the Set for the specified key from the Map
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this. The `Class<N>` arguments arent't needed at all: in `subscribe` you can extract the argument via [`ParameterizedType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments()), and in `dispatch` you simply cast to `Class<N>` the object returned by `item.getClass()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not sure if I missing something as well :) but the fact that `item` may be of a *subtype* of `N` means that you cannot simply cast it to `Class<N>`

Comment: I see -  then the missing thing are specs, it's my fault :) this code is intended to be used in a simple project, so it's ok to assume that item **can't** be a subtype of `N`. However this answer makes a point that effectively messed up some tests I wrote, so + 1

Comment: Glad it was of some use, I l learned something new about generics too but I am not quite sure what :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the super types of `subscriber.getClass()`, by `Class.getGenericSuperclass/getGenericInterfaces()`, then inspect them to extract which `N` really is, by `ParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()`

For example

```
public class SportsLover implements Subscriber<SportsNews>
{
    void onNews(SportsNews news){ ... }
}

if subscriber is an instance of SportsLover

Class clazz = subscriber.getClass();   // SportsLover.class

// the super type: Subscriber<SportsNews>
Type superType = clazz.getGenericInterfaces()[0];  

// the type arg: SportsNews
Type typeN = ((ParameterizedType)superType).getgetActualTypeArguments()[0];  

Class clazzN = (Class)typeN;
```

That works for simple cases.

For more complicated case, we'll need more complicated algorithms on types.

Comment: Yes, I read that in the [Gafter's article](http://gafter.blogspot.it/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html). That's not the hard part, at the moment. Can you elaborate on the rest?

Comment: your problem doesn't need "type token"

Comment: I don't know what my problem needs. Reflection? Generics? Polymorphism? I'm open minded, I'd just like `Aggregator` to compile. Your solution suggests how to extract the type argument: this is fine, but it's not the only problem. Try to [make it work](http://pastebin.com/LVbcw0Nv)

Comment: You need reflection, to extract N for any given Subscriber object. that's what my code demonstrated, extract `classN` from `subscriber`.

Comment: OK, but this is just the first step to solve the problem. Now I need to somehow keep a map between `Class`es and `Set<Subscriber>`s, and dinamically put and retrieve `Subscriber` in the approprate set in a type safe manner: **that** is the real problem. Check the provided link

Answer (score 0):

A way could be use a [TypeToken](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) to hold `N`

```
 Type typeOfCollectionOfFoo = new TypeToken<Collection<Foo>>(){}.getType()
```

To make your code work

Declare your class as

```
public static class Aggregator<N extends News>
```

Change method signature to

```
 private Set<Subscriber<N>> getSubscribersFor() {
```

And you are done.

Comment: That is not the problem. I don't need an external class because I already know that real subscribers implement a generic interface, and can use that to extract the type. To answer the question, you need to make [this](http://pastebin.com/LVbcw0Nv) work

Comment: `Aggregator` is not supposed to be parameterized, it should be a container of heterogeneous news. The alternative (maybe I forgot to mention it) is making a `static` method in each `News` subtype to return the parameterized aggregator, but still there's no way of enforcing this at the language level - I mean, `News` should declare something like `abstract static Aggregator<this.class> getAggregator()`, which in Java is prohibited in a number of ways