# How to use collections and generics with wildcards?

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard

First I will try to explain the idea behind this code.
I have a bunch of classes (Processors) that can process a certain type of other classes (Processables). I have a List of Processors to execute them in a certain order. I have a Map that will retrieve me the data to process (Processables) for a certain Processor.
It looks somehow like this.

```
public abstract class AbstractProcessable {
    ...
}

public class DummyProcessable extends AbstractProcessable {
   ...
}

public abstract class AbstractProcessor<T extends AbstractProcessable> {
    public abstract void process(List<T> listOfProcessables);
}

public class DummyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<DummyProcessable> {

    @Override
    public void process(List<DummyProcessable> listToProcess) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine so far. There are no compilation errors. But now I have a class like the following:

```
public class RandomClass {

    private List<AbstractProcessor<? extends AbstractProcessable>> processors;

    private Map<Class<? extends AbstractProcessor>, List<? extends AbstractProcessable>> data;

    public RandomClass() {
        processors = new ArrayList<>();
        processors.add(new DummyProcessor());

        data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put(DummyProcessor.class, new ArrayList<DummyProcessable>());

        processAll();
    }

    private void processAll() {
        for (AbstractProcessor<? extends AbstractProcessable> processor : processors) {
            List<? extends AbstractProcessable> dataToProcess;
            dataToProcess = data.get(processor);
            processor.process(dataToProcess); // compile error
        }
    }
}
```

Compile error:

```
    The method process(List<capture#4-of ? extends AbstractProcessable>) in the type AbstractProcessor<capture#4-of ? extends AbstractProcessable> is not applicable for the arguments (List<capture#5-of ? extends AbstractProcessable>)
```

I know it might be a bit difficult to read, but I tried to simplify it as much as possible. I'm also not that good with generics so maybe I used some wildcards wrong?
Can anyone help me to solve that problem?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: please post full error you get, to check in detail

Comment: can you add "@Override" annotation to process() method of the derived class and see if the compiler reports any new errors?

Comment: Override added. Override was there all the time, I just forgot it here. Also the error message is now code, since it was altered otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I asked [a similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038298/can-generics-and-super-type-tokens-help-to-build-a-type-safe-news-aggregator) some time ago. Short answer is that you can't use such a map in the way you intend to. The good news is that you don't need it ;)

The problem is that Java generics are a compile-time thing (as you may already know), and they solely exist at compile time, which **is not** when you actually fill your `List`. You cannot find a way to express your idea in Java, even if it seems a perfectly legitimate one.

You may find [Super Type Tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.it/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) useful to extract parameters in certain cases and avoid the user to supply an explicit parameter if it's suitable (however mind [the limitations](http://gafter.blogspot.it/2007/05/limitation-of-super-type-tokens.html) and consider if they can really add some value).

In short, you'll end up with a field like

```
private Map<Class<?>, List<?>> data;
```

(or you can use [Guava's `Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) implementation for this), using some casts and shouting some warnings out, and relying on your program logic for the client code to be type safe. I used that approach in my code and it never failed so far.

This is my code. I think it's exactly your case, just replace `Subscriber<T>` and `Message` with your `Processor<T>` and `Processable`

```
public class MessageBus {

    public enum Action {
        CREATE, REMOVE, UPDATE, DELETE;
    }

    private static Map<Class<?>, Set<Subscriber<?>>> subscriptions;

    static {
        subscriptions = new HashMap<Class<?>, Set<Subscriber<?>>>();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> void publish(T message, Action action) {
        Set<Subscriber<?>> set = getSubscribersFor(message.getClass());

        if (set == null)
            return;

        for (Subscriber<?> subscriber: set) {
            ((Subscriber<T>) subscriber).onMessage(message, action);
        }
    }

    public static <T> void subscribe(Class<T> type, Subscriber<T> subscriber) {
        Set<Subscriber<?>> set = getSubscribersFor(type);

        if (set == null) {
            set = new HashSet<Subscriber<?>>();
            subscriptions.put(type, set);
        }

        set.add(subscriber);
    }

    public static <T> void unsuscribe(Class<T> type, Subscriber<T> subscriber) {
        Set<Subscriber<?>> set = getSubscribersFor(type);
        set.remove(subscriber);
    }

    private static Set<Subscriber<?>> getSubscribersFor(Class<?> topic) {
        return subscriptions.get(topic);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, you seem to know what you talk about and I would accept your answer as the correct one, but I'm missing the explanation as to **why** this does not work. Where is the problem, I don't understand the error message.

Comment: @noone [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12534510/315306) may help you to understand the error message because the long answer doesn't really fit in a comment. I suppose you know how Java type system works: an `Integer` is a valid argument for a method which accepts an `Object` because of the subtype relationship between `Object` and `Integer`. Generics types are said to be **invariant** on the type argument, ie `List<Integer>` is **not** a subtype of `List<Object>`. It's a rule. (continue)

Comment: @noone See my answer for a posible, easy to test, explanation.

Comment: (continue) In your code you have two **unknown** types: unknown means that since the compiler can't find their definition anywhere, it cannot even infer a subtype relationship on the base types. For example `Long` and `Integer` extends `Number`. You can declare a `List<? extends Number>` and assign the reference to a `List<Integer>`, but you loose the ability to invoke `add(T)` on such a list, because the compiler hasn't be told any *real* type definition, and it uses a ficticious type referred to as `capture#N`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the issue here is that:

1. `? extends AbstractProcessable` from `private List<AbstractProcessor<? extends AbstractProcessable>> processors;` and
2. `? extends AbstractProcessable` from `List<? extends AbstractProcessable> dataToProcess;`

are not of the same type. `? extends AbstractProcessable` represents an unknown subclass of `AbstractProcessable`, nothing forces that the two unknown should be the same (that is why you get the error, since the unknown: `capture#4-of ?`  is different then the unknown: `capture#5-of ?`). 
Not sure about the purpose of your `RandomClass` but I would change it to be of a `<T extends AbstractProcessable>` and use `T` to define the list and the map. This way the list and the map will have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

to me it sounds like you imported 2 different List classes in these. Check import section and make sure

```
import java.util.List
```

is in both (or whatever List type you need)

Just as the first guess, without checking your code in detail :)

Comment: That at least is not the problem. Though I wish it would be so easy!